# How to load data from two tables in Crystal Reports to dataset in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I want to load data from two tables of SQL Server in  C# into a dataset of Crystal Reports. When I try it this way:

```
private void LoadReport()
{
        try
        {
            SQLConn.sqL = (@"SELECT TD.InvoiceNo, 
                P.Description,
                P.Product, 
                TD.ItemPrice, 
                TD.Quantity, 
                TD.Amount, 
                TD.DiscPercent, 
                TD.DiscAmount, 
                TD.NetAmount, 
                Cu.CusName FROM product as P, 
                transactionDetails as TD,
                customer as Cu 
                WHERE P.ProductNo = '2' And TD.CusID = Cu.CusID");
            SQLConn.ConnDB();
            SQLConn.cmd = new SqlCommand(SQLConn.sqL, SQLConn.conn);
            SQLConn.da = new SqlDataAdapter(SQLConn.cmd);              

            ProductDataset ds = new ProductDataset();
            SQLConn.da.Fill(ds);              

            rptProduct report = new rptProduct();

            report.SetDataSource(ds);
            

            RptProductViewer1.ReportSource = report;

            RptProductViewer1.Refresh();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Interaction.MsgBox(ex.ToString());
        }
}
```

I got an error and data is not loaded into the dataset whereas the query is perfect I have checked in SQL Server query executer.

Please tell me the best way to load multiple tables data into Crystal Reports

Got this Exception...

[image]

After adding ds.tables["transactiondetails"] i got this exception

[image]

Comment: What error are you receiving?  I presume it's an exception?  What's the exception type?  What's the `ex.Message` property?

Comment: see Image Description ..i have added in detail

Comment: look into your ProductDataset if you created a datatable on it then you should load its index report.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[1]);

Comment: after adding table name in dataset .i got another exception..see 2nd image description

Comment: Now in new error, on top you can see any row which violating your own rules Unique and not null. Try to empty your database rows first, also tag me in your next comment else i will notify about your comment